# Show that $F(B)=B$and $F(C)=C$ if $F: \mathcal{P}A \to \mathcal{P}A$ and that $F$ has the monotonicity property

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Assume that $F: \mathcal{P}A \to \mathcal{P}A$ and that $F$ has the monotonicity property:
$$X \subseteq Y \subseteq A \implies F(X) \subseteq F(Y)$$
Define
$$B = \bigcap \{ X \subseteq A | F(X) \subseteq X \} \; \mathtt{and} \; C = \bigcup \{ X \subseteq A | X \subseteq F(X) \}$$
Show that $F(B)=B$ and $F(C)=C$.

---

So far I can get:
1. $F(A) \subseteq A \;\&  \; \varnothing \subseteq F(\varnothing)$
2. given any $X_1 \subseteq F(X_1)$ and $F(X_2) \subseteq X_2$ $(X_1 ,X_2 \subseteq A)$
    I have  $B \subseteq X_2 ,F(B) \subseteq F(X_2) \subseteq X_2$ and  $X_1 \subseteq C, X_1 \subseteq F(X_1) \subseteq F(C)$

But:
I cannot find a way to show the relation between $F(B)$ and $B$.What should I do?

Comment: It's not 100% a duplicate, but the answers on that link should take you pretty much all the way on this proof.

Comment: @AsafKaragila ok,I'll have a look